# Is it always safe to cast char to int and int to double?

Tags: c

For both little endian and big endian?

What if they are in an array? Is it safe too?

Comment: Casting itself is safe. Only if you're type-punning does endian matter.

Comment: Endianness and arrays make no difference. A cast is a type conversion. It acts on the value in question, not on bytes in memory.

Comment: Nit: I think casting a *64-bit integer* to a *64-bit double* could result in precision loss above `2^53` or so..? (But I'm pretty sure that's not the focus of the question.)

Comment: @Mysticial casting is not always safe in itself, there are some undefined behaviors when casting from float types to integer types (e.g., as in C99, 6.3.1.4).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Endianness.

As you can see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types), char is almost certainly going to be 8 bit, so casting that to integer is always safe in every sense of the word.

Casting an int to a double, however, is not. The number 2^63 - 10, e.g., cannot be represented  exactly in a 64 bit double. Read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) Here, a cast will lead to the number being truncated, and thus precision loss.

Fortunately, all 32 bit ints can be casted without loss, so if your ints 32 bits long, you're good.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as long as you are type casting regular C variables, it is safe.

You only need to worry about endian if you are altering or moving with the raw bytes that make up those variables.